# Export Processing Project as aWeb App

Tags: java, applet, processing

I've made a cool processing project that I would like to embed on the web; however, it uses 3rd party Java libraries to access an sqlite database. For this reason, the normal export-to-javascript which has worked well for me in the past is just not capable enough here. How can I make my Processing project into a Java applet that will allow it to be run remotely?

Comment: please consider upvoting or accepting this answer if it was useful, and/or providing your own answer if you figured this out elsewhere...

Answer (score 1):

This depends upon what version of Processing you are using...

It was only in the final move to 2.0 that they got rid of the 'Export to Applet' option, so if you can make do with a 2.x-beta version, you're golden.

Of course, that's just through the PDE - so failing the ability to move to an earlier version, the library itself should be able to handle it still, from a different IDE, say Eclipse or NetBeans...

I guess the other option would be to see if you can port your library to a JavaScript library ?

Comment: I usually use emacs. Using the CLI or Eclipse, where can I learn how to build my Processing project into an app[let]?

Comment: you just right click the Class file, and Eclipse will prompt you with a wizard... There's a bunch of posts on SO about this. I assume there's command line tools to do it as well though.